# Formatting float inputs in C

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

I am quite new to C programming. Currently doing this CS50 course where the get_float function ensures that my user input is a float.

I use a do while loop to ensure that the input is not negative and if it is, I re-prompt the user for an input.

My question is, is there a way I can reject the users input if the user's input is greater than two decimal places and then re-prompt them for an input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do this you should get a string and do your own parsing to check how many decimal places there are.

Comment: Since the `get_float` returns a floating-point number, not the numeral (original string) the user entered, it is impossible to distinguish input of “3.00” from “3.000”. On the other hand, if your goal is to detect whether the number has a non-zero digit after the second decimal place, that cannot be done perfectly because both the input “3.2” and “3.2000000476837158203125” result in the same return value, 3.2000000476837158203125 (assuming IEEE-754 binary32 for `float`). There are ways to check you are at least close to a number without a non-zero digit after the second decimal place…

Comment: … However, is that really needed for the assignment you are doing? Likely, you can simply multiply the input by 100 and round it to the nearest integer, and then use the result as an integer number of cents in the assignment we have seen asked about too many times on Stack Overflow. If the assignment does not explicitly say to reject such numbers entered by the user, then do not go to this trouble.

Comment: First, is the phrase "greater than two decimal places" defined? Is the number 123456.0 more than two decimal places? How about 12.53? One could argue that those numbers have 1 and 2 decimal places respectively (i.e. digits right of the decimal point) or 6 and 2 (i.e. digits left of the decimal point) or 7 and 4 (i.e. total digits). I'll guess they mean "digits right of the decimal point" but it's not clear to me. For that matter, if the author is a non-native English speaker, they might be asking whether there are decimal points in more than two places (i.e. reject 1.2.3)

Comment: @EricPostpischil , yes the assignment does not require it but I was just curious.I'll just go with the simple method for now. Thank you.

Comment: @Howlium I am a native English speaker so I apologise if I wasn't clear enough. I thought it was a universally understood that number of decimal places refer to the number of digits after the decimal point, i.e. right. But I will endeavour to be more clear in the future. So, just to be clear, I wanted a method to reject an input of say 12.834 but be able to accept inputs such as 12.81 and 12.7.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

get_float is a CS50 only term. There is no way to limit the length after the decimal.

Eventually you will switch to scanf which is the real way to get input in c but wait until you reach pointers to worry about that.

Use %.2f when you print the number it will drop off any other decimals.

ex. printf("Your change is %.2f", change)

### This would show .02 even if the number was .029

If you need to round up use round(change)

ex. printf("Your change is %.2f", round(change))

this would show .30

you would need to include <math.h> header to use round function.

Comment: And eventually, after using `scanf` for a while, you start using `fgets` and `sscanf` instead :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This kind of eases my worries about the cs50 course not having as much depth as I would have liked. If I learn more comprehensive methods later down the line, that is great.